# Hadoop MR mapper class not found in scala play framework

Tags: hadoop, playframework, mapreduce

I'm trying to run a MR job in Play 2.0.1 scala, but I can't get the mapper class loaded in the job classpath. Every time I run the job in hadoop I get a classnotfoundexception.  I already added (in several different ways) the reference to the class in order to load the corresponding jar, but without success. Any clue will be appreciated.

Thanks!
-carlos.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were running MR job from dev mode. There are couple of issues running MR job from play dev mode. One of issue is the mapper/reducer classes are not found on TaskTracker nodes because the jar with mapper/reducer is not created yet. Here is my solution:

http://ben-tech.blogspot.com/2013/04/run-mapreduce-in-play-development-mode.html

Another issue is caused by the class loader used in Play run command. Run command creates a class loader that has only dependency jars so that you classes are not in the classpaths when you use Class.forName. I don't have a solution for this yet.